# Rails Survey - How to show the number of the current question out of total?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to rails and have been working on creating a survey tool. This is how my models are structured:

```
class Study < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :questions, dependent: :destroy
  validates :study_name, presence: true, length: { minimum: 5, maximum: 100 }
end


class Question < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :study
  has_many :answers, dependent: :destroy
  validates :question, presence: true, length: { minimum: 5, maximum: 100 }
  def next_question
    study.questions.where('id > ?', id).first
  end
end


class Answer < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :participant
  validates :text, presence: true, length: { minimum: 5, maximum: 100 }
end


class Participant < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :answers, dependent: :destroy
end
```

When a participant is answering a survey they are shown one question at a time.

What I am trying to achieve is showing the participant the *current question they are on* out of the *total number of questions*

I am able to get the total number of questions by using this code:

```
<%=@study.questions.count %>
```

But I am not sure how to get the current question with how I have written the answers view in new.html.erb. This is the code in that file:

```
<div class="wrap">


  <h1 class="welcome-header study-name"><%= @study.study_name %></h1>
  <div class="study-wave5"> <%= image_tag  "wave5.svg" %></div>
  <div class="section colour-section">

    <h2><%= @question.question %></h2>
    <h2> 1 out of <%=@study.questions.count %></h2>

    <%= form_with model: @answer, url: study_question_answers_path(@study, @question), local: true do |form| %>
      <%= form.hidden_field :participant_id %>

      <% @question.answers.each do |answer| %>


        <% if answer.errors.any? %>
          <div id="error_explanation">
            <h2>
              <%= pluralize(answer.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
              this answer from being saved:
            </h2>
            <ul>
              <% answer.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                <li><%= msg %></li>
              <% end %>
            </ul>
          </div>
        <% end %>

      <% end %>

      <%= form.text_area :text, class: 'textfield', id: 'textarea'%><br>
      <div id="textarea_feedback"></div>
      <div class="submit-btn"><%= form.submit%></div>
    <% end %>

  </div>

</div>
```

Here is a picture to show what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use

```
<%= @study.questions.where('id <= ?', @question.id).count %> out of <%=@study.questions.count %>
```

but I would use a different field to order your questions.  Look at something like acts_as_list gem, you will almost certainly want to reorder your questions in some way.

Comment: This worked perfectly and it's so simple! Thank you so much for this! My questions are ordered in order of date created currently. Something I will have to think about if the user wants the questions to be randomised for every participant if i choose to do so in the future. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I would just add another column to your Question model, called question_number and use that.

It's clear and doesn't require you to hack something together to work, aka Principle of Least Astonishment.